# Android Teleop App - "App Start Failed"

Tags: ros, turtlebot, teleop, android, teleoperation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I've today started to toy around with the Android apps. Of the three I have tried, Chirp and Follower work fine, however basic Teleop isn't working at all. Teleoperation isn't an issue with controlling the Turtlebot from a workstation. Would anyone have any suggestions out there to why I would be getting the below error?

Thank you.

[INFO] [WallTime: 1321906461.485421] start_app: turtlebot_teleop/android_teleop

[INFO] [WallTime: 1321906461.486866] Loading app: turtlebot_teleop/android_teleop

[INFO] [WallTime: 1321906461.625926] Launching: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/turtlebot_apps/turtlebot_teleop/app/android_teleop.launch

[ERROR] [WallTime: 1321906461.685181] app start failed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12009/android-teleop-app---%22app-start-failed%22/) by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2011-11-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the same problem. I think this is being fixed in the next release of ROS. Please check out  https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/rev/5407c701e391

---

Originally posted by [Robert Buzink](https://answers.ros.org/users/1627/robert-buzink/) with karma: 41 on 2012-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0